# How to apply aggregation on the first field of first object of a array of objects in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, embedded-documents

I have data in the format given below.

```
{
"_id" : 19,
"name" : "Gisela Levin",
"scores" : [
        {
                "score" : 44.51211101958831,
                "type" : "exam"
        },
        {
                "score" : 0.6578497966368002,
                "type" : "quiz"
        },
        {
                "score" : 93.36341655949683,
                "type" : "homework"
        }
],
"studentType" : "poor"}
```

Now i want to find the average of **exam score** for each **studentType** and i have written a query

`db.student.aggregate(
    {$project : {_id : 0, studentType : 1, "scores.0.score" : 1}},
    {$group : {_id : "$studentType", AverageMarks : {$avg : "$scores.0.score"}}}
)`

But i am getting this answer

```
{ "_id" : "good", "AverageMarks" : null }
```

{ "_id" : "avg", "AverageMarks" : null }
{ "_id" : "poor", "AverageMarks" : null }